# Delay a script from running until all assets have loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, sinemacula

### A Brief Explanation

This is not as basic as it sounds, so please do not skip to answering before you have read and understood what I am trying to do :-).

I have an object called `SineMacula` which contains a few base functions like so (ignore the `ready` function for the moment):

```
(function(global, $){

    // MOST CODE STRIPT OUT HERE */

    /**
     * Sine Macula Run
     * Makes it easy to write plugins for the Sine Macula library
     *
     * @param function callback
     */
    SM.run = run;
    function run(callback){
        // Call the function with the Sine Macula
        // and jQuery objects
        callback(SM, $);
    }

    /**
     * Sine Macula Ready
     * Executes code once the Sine Macula and jQuery
     * libraries are ready
     *
     * @param function callback
     */
    SM.ready = ready;
    function ready(callback){
        // Call the function with the Sine Macula
        // and jQuery objects
        jQuery(function($) {
            callback(SM, $);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Sine Macula Load
     * Load the Sine Macula Libraries and Plugins
     * into the current document
     *
     * The options:
     * - package: the package of libraries to load
     * - packageURL: a remote source to load the package details from
     * - libraries: any additional libraries to load
     *
     * @param object parameter The options for the Sine Macula load
     */
    SM.load = load;
    function load(options){
        // BUILD A QUERY HERE
        // ...
        // Complete the url by appending the query
        url = '//libraries.sinemaculammviii.com/'+query;        
        // Append the script tag to the end of the document
        script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = url;
        $('head')[0].appendChild(script);       
    }
})(this, this.jQuery);
```

The `load()` function simply loads in all relevant plugins/libraries for the page by appending  a relevant script tag to the `head` of the page.

All the scripts in the loaded pages are run as a callback to the function called `run`. This ensures that both `jQuery` and `SineMacula` are passed through to the plugins.

### The Problem

This is where the issue lies, because the libraries are being loaded into the `SineMacula` object, there is no way to detect whether they have been loaded or not.

For example, if one of the libraries contains a function plugin called `setDate()`, and I run:

```
SM.setDate()
```

This will not necessarily work because the `setDate()` function may not have been loaded into the `SineMacula` object yet and therefore it will return an 'Uncaught TypeError...'.

Can anybody advise of a good adaptation to the `SineMacula.ready()` function to detect whether or not the libraries are present?

**Please do not make suggestions to do with the `jQuery.load()` function, I am well aware of it.**

I do not want the solution to be a callback of the function `load()`, unless absolutely necessary.

I hope this makes sense, if not let me know and I will post more info. Wanted to keep it as brief as possible.

Thanks in Advance

**UPDATE**

Forgot to mention that I have a testing page [here](https://libraries.sinemaculammviii.com/test.php) where you can see the error I am getting and get a better understanding of what I am doing :-)

Comment: @AbdullahJibaly I do :-) if you want to see the error in action on a testing page then go to http://libraries.sinemaculammviii.com/test.php

Comment: Why are using manipulating DOM to create your script element insetead of using jQuery?

Comment: @Rob Only because jQuery added some weird attributes to the script tag. Want to revert back to jQuery, but wasn't sure what the attributes did. Something like `async`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, its the user that invokes `SM.run()` from within their script, which then calls `SM.load()`, which loads other parts of the library.

So if that's the case, then no matter what, their script will finish executing before any other parts of the library can be loaded.

I think what you'd need to do is have a requirement that the user have their `.run()` in a separate script from the rest of their code. Then you can use `document.write` to load the other scripts. This will cause them to load and block the next script, which would contain the rest of the user's code:

```
function load(options){
    // BUILD A QUERY HERE
    // ...
    // Complete the url by appending the query
    document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" ',
                            ' src="//libraries.sinemaculammviii.com/' + query,
                            '"><\/scr' + 'ipt>');      
}
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/your/lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    SineMacula.load('all');
</script>

<!-- The document.write will write the new script here, and it will be loaded
         syncronously, so it will block. -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    // code that uses the loaded library parts
</script>
```

Comment: please don't recommend using `document.write`

Comment: @AbdullahJibaly: Why, it's a very useful tool in a situation like this.

Comment: Please see my edit as I have posted a link that may change your answers. It is much easier to understand when you see the structure of the page :-)

Comment: @user1689607 You wont be able to find `SM.run` in the script as that particular script is minified, but to answer your question, the load is not called from within `run()`

Comment: @BenCarey: Looking at the site, it seems as though you have one script that calls `.load()`, then the next script runs the code that relies on the loaded library parts. So using my answer should take care of it. By using `document.write`, the new script will be added after the `.load('all')` script, and before the `test.js` script.

Comment: There are (very few) examples where `document.write` is needed, but this is not one of them. This gives no advantage of what the OP had which is much better (creating a script element).

Comment: @AbdullahJibaly: This is absolutely one of them. It inserts the loaded script after the current script, and still loads it in a blocking manner, so it will be available before the next script runs. What OP has will load the script asynchronously. This will not.

Comment: He did not add an `async` attribute, so it will block until the js resource is loaded.

Comment: "Scripts without async or defer attributes are fetched and executed immediately, before the browser continues to parse the page."

Comment: @AbdullahJibaly: Scripts loaded by creating a new `script` element will be loaded asynchronously with respect to the rest of the page. In other words, it will not run until all the scripts that were directly written into the page have executed.

Comment: @AbdullahJibaly: None of that is relevant to creating a new script using `document.createElement`. All of it is relevant to scripts written in the document *(which includes scripts written using `document.write`)*

Comment: But even in that case why not simply have a callback when the script is loaded. It does it anyways (with the SM.* methods).

Comment: @AbdullahJibaly: That's up to OP to decide. I really don't know what is running where and when. If the script is being created in the `.load()`, and then there's a separate `.ready()` that accepts a callback, then if OP could make the new script available to `.ready()`, the callback could be assigned as the `onload` handler of the new script. I just don't know what is intended.

Comment: @user1689607 Sorry for the delay. Is what you have posted not what I am already doing? That is why I am confused that it doesn't work! I am not using `document.write` but the script is still being written to the page before the `test.js` is loaded

Comment: @user1689607 I have applied your fix and it has not solved the issue. Very oddly, `test.js` is executing before the loaded library, even though it is loaded after. Why is this?

Comment: @BenCarey: Have you gotten things working? Looking at your page, the script is in the right place, but I can't tell what you did.

Comment: @user1689607 I am using `document.write` and everything seems to be working. As the `load()` method will only be called at the beginning of the page, `document.write` is a suitable solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I'm answering your question given some context is missing, but you might want to use `Deferred`s:

```
SM.ready = ready;
function ready(callback){
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    // Call the function with the Sine Macula
    // and jQuery objects
    jQuery(function($) {
        deferred.resolve();
        if (typeof(callback) === "function") {
            callback(SM, $);
        }
    });
    return deferred;
}
```

Now you can do something like:

```
SM.ready().done(function() {
    // everything is now set.
});
```